# SQL query for concatinating current row value with previous row values

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have source data in following format.

```
RN  ID  NAME
1   1   P
2   2   Q
3   3   R
4   4   S
5   5   T
6   1   A
7   2   B
8   3   C
9   4   D
10  5   E
```

I need following output.

```
RN  ID  NAME
1   1   P
2   2   PQ
3   3   PQR
4   4   PQRS
5   5   PQRST
6   1   A
7   2   AB
8   3   ABC
9   4   ABCD
10  5   ABCDE
```

Kindly provide SQL query for this.

Comment: In SQL table rows are unordered,..

Comment: Yes for that i had used row_number function and sorted them according to that. but was not able to get the result as per the output.

Comment: Specify your RDBMS

Comment: @NaveenKumar you need to specify the order of rows, right now, there is no clear order in the data

Comment: Do you have a fixed and known amount of ID's, or is this dynamic? For a fixed amount, a bunch of self joins would do it, for dynamic you'd probably want some CTE magic.

Comment: @w͏̢in̡͢g͘̕ed̨p̢͟a͞n͏͏t̡͜͝he̸r̴ Im using Oracle 11g

Comment: @Radim Bača  The order of rows is what i had specified in the question.

Comment: @Ola Berntsson The amount of ID's is dynamic. I have just posted only five ID's for sample.

Comment: You should provide us with some guide which data should be concatenated together. Why (2,Q) is concatenated with (1,P) but not with (1,A)?

Comment: @Radim Bača The data should only be concatinated if the value of the ID column is in increasing order. Else the value should be the initial value.

Comment: See, and here comes the problem. There is no inherent order of rows in relation. You should probably add an attribute `order` which specifies it.

Comment: Does the table has any otherr column?

Comment: @Radim Bača I have added rownum column for maintaing the order of rows as u said

Comment: @Naveen Kumar: That you show 1|P before 1|A doesn't mean that it's the same in the database table. Data in a table is considered unordered. So we could just as well name 1|A first and 1|P as the sixth entry (or at any other position for that matter). Hence Radim's question: Why (2,Q) is concatenated with (1,P) but not with (1,A). You need some column to indicate an order or group.

Comment: @Valli no but i have added rownum for preserving the order of rows

Comment: @Thorsten Kettner I have added rownum kindly check

Comment: `ROWNUM` is a reserved word in Oracle. It's the number of the row the DBMS happens to read the row from the table. It is not a consistent/deterministic value you can rely on. If you want to read data from a table in a certain order, then you must use `ORDER BY`. Which `ORDER BY` clause would you specify to get the data ordered as you are showing?

Comment: Ah, I see you call this `RN` now. So it's an additional column in your table? I would rather expect some kind of grouping column, e.g. value 1 for the first five records, value 2 for the second five. But well, I would neither expect a column that is called ID to have duplicates in a table :-(

Comment: How is it possible that people have upvoted "Kindly provide SQL query for this". Clearly there is zero effort here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/aabf7a/3)

**Oracle 11g R2 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE table_name ( RN, ID, NAME ) As
SELECT  1, 1,   'P' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT  2, 2,   'Q' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT  3, 3,   'R' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT  4, 4,   'S' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT  5, 5,   'T' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT  6, 1,   'A' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT  7, 2,   'B' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT  8, 3,   'C' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT  9, 4,   'D' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 10, 5,   'E' FROM DUAL
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT RN,
       ID,
       REPLACE( SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH( NAME, ',' ), ',' ) AS NAME
FROM   TABLE_NAME
START WITH ID = 1
CONNECT BY PRIOR ID + 1 = ID
AND        PRIOR ASCII(NAME) + 1 = ASCII(NAME)
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/aabf7a/3/0)**:

```
| RN | ID |  NAME |
|----|----|-------|
|  1 |  1 |     P |
|  2 |  2 |    PQ |
|  3 |  3 |   PQR |
|  4 |  4 |  PQRS |
|  5 |  5 | PQRST |
|  6 |  1 |     A |
|  7 |  2 |    AB |
|  8 |  3 |   ABC |
|  9 |  4 |  ABCD |
| 10 |  5 | ABCDE |
```

**Query 2**:

```
SELECT RN,
       ID,
       REPLACE( SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH( NAME, ',' ), ',' ) AS NAME
FROM   TABLE_NAME
START WITH ID = 1
CONNECT BY PRIOR ID + 1 = ID
AND        PRIOR RN + 1 = RN
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/aabf7a/3/1)**:

```
| RN | ID |  NAME |
|----|----|-------|
|  1 |  1 |     P |
|  2 |  2 |    PQ |
|  3 |  3 |   PQR |
|  4 |  4 |  PQRS |
|  5 |  5 | PQRST |
|  6 |  1 |     A |
|  7 |  2 |    AB |
|  8 |  3 |   ABC |
|  9 |  4 |  ABCD |
| 10 |  5 | ABCDE |
```

Comment: The best way to thank in Stack overflow is to accept it as answer/Upvote:-)